# Replace the 5th character in a string with a space if its a hyphen

Tags: powerquery

Is there an easy way to change a hyphen in a string of text to a space ONLY if it appears in the 5th position in the text?

I.e., the string "ABCD-EFG" would become "ABCD EFG" but "ABCDEF-G" would be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nora has the right idea but I can't use _ in a comment on her answer, so

```
transform = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1", each try if Text.Range(_, 4, 1)="-" then Text.ReplaceRange(_, 4, 1, " ") else _ otherwise _, type text}})
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that looks exactly right. Only issue is I keep getting an error it can't find the column. It is called 'Column1'. I have tried renaming it and using the new name and still get the same error. ie. @Expression.Error: The column 'TESTCOL' of the table wasn't found." when I've tried a different name in the code = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"TESTCOL",each Text.Start(_,4) & Text.Replace(Text.Range(_,4,1),"-"," ") & Text.Range(_,5), type text}}).  Probably something obvious I'm missing (staring at this problem too long I expect!)

Comment: You need to replace Source with the name of whatever your prior step name is, like potentially transform = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",  if you renamed something prior to this step

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That works and makes sense.  Just got to figure out how to ignore the values where Text.Length < 5 as they throw an error but a problem for another day.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Appreciate your help - finding the M language syntax a steep learning curve and these examples really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the 5th character of a Text using [Text.Range](https://www.powerquery.io/text/text.range) (the 5th character range would be index 4 to 1 since 4th would be D, meaning index 4 would start capturing from the hyphen after 'D') and then check if it equals a hyphen using [Text.Equals](https://www.powerquery.io/text/text.equals).

If it's true, you can replace the same range with a space using [Text.ReplaceRange](https://www.powerquery.io/text/text.replacerange), otherwise return the default value.

```
if (Text.Equals(Text.Range("ABCD-EFG", 4, 1), "-")) then
  Text.ReplaceRange("ABCD-EFG", 4, 1, " ")
else
  "ABCD-EFG"
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I want it to work for a column of any values, not a specific string ie,

Column1
----------
AAAA-BBB  -> AAAA BBB  {hyphen replaced}
AAAABBBB -> AAAABBBB  {hyphen ignored}
ABABAB-A -> ABABAB-A   {hyphen ignored}
BBBB-CCC -> BBBB CCC    {hyphen replaced}

etc....